# jQuery Waypoints - highlight paragraph on scrolldown

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm looking to use Waypoints to highlight certain areas of a paragraph as the user scrolls down. For instance, if I added a span to a certain point in a graph, that span would highlight when the user reaches that point, while the rest of the graph becomes opaque.

```
<div id="wrap">
<h1>header</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <span class="one"> 
Ut enim ad minim dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit </span>        
lor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod lor sit amet,
consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod.</p>
</div>
```

I'd like to replicate that effect over multiple spans within a graph. 
Thanks!